# Too many arguments for mapping form in playframework scala

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, mapping

I have 26 arguments for mapping method in form playframework. But, it is failed.

```
mapping(
    "id" -> number,
    "field_1" -> text,
    "field_2" -> text,
    "field_3" -> text,
    "field_4" -> text,
    "field_5" -> text,
    "field_6" -> text,
    "field_7" -> text,
    "field_8" -> text,
    "field_9" -> text,
    "field_10" -> text,
    "field_11" -> text,
    "field_12" -> text,
    "field_13" -> text,
    "field_14" -> text,
    "field_15" -> text,
    "field_16" -> text,
    "field_17" -> text,
    "field_18" -> text,
    "field_19" -> text,
    "field_20" -> text,
    "field_21" -> text,
    "field_22" -> text,
    "field_23" -> text,
    "field_24" -> text,
    "field_25" -> text
)(Data.apply)(Data.unapply)
```

But, I dont know how to fix it, can you help me, thank you so much!

Comment: Have you followed the proper steps to make a form? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms Do all of these fields correspond with a form field in your view? It's unclear from your example what is wrong without the context of the rest of your view/form/whatever.

Comment: @KTu : can you please check the answers - comment if you still have problems or accept one of them otherwise? So it helps others and gives feedback if the answer is correct or at least help.

Answer (score 0):

You hit the maximum upper limit, see the [Play Doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms):

> Note: Maximum number of fields for a single tuple or mapping is 22 due
>   to the way form handling is implemented. If you have more than 22
>   fields in your form, you should break down your forms using lists or
>   nested values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than 22 fields, you hit the limit to have unapply and tupled method. One way you can do is breaking down the case class to have multiple peices as following (the example is from play docs):

```
case class AddressData(street: String, city: String)

case class UserAddressData(name: String, address: AddressData)
val userFormNested: Form[UserAddressData] = Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> text,
    "address" -> mapping(
    "street" -> text,
    "city" -> text
    )(AddressData.apply)(AddressData.unapply)
  )(UserAddressData.apply)(UserAddressData.unapply)
)
```